# Paint light scratches repair

Tags: paint, paint-scratches

Hi I own Renault Megane Mk3 for while and car's paint is almost full with small scratches due to hard cleaning( car was cleaned by a hard surface ), I know its stupid thing to make but it wasn't my fault. 
So is there is way to fix this? Rather than repainting the whole car because its quite expensive in my country.

You will get how scratches look like in photos.

[image]

Those  circles that appears when a light reflect on car's surface.
 If photos are not clear I'll provide another photos

[image]

Comment: It's actually not that difficult to paint the car yourself:  http://amzn.com/1932494227

Comment: i don't think I'm going to do this right, because I have no experience in car painting

Comment: The book is written for people with no experience.  It also covers how to buff out old superficially scratched up paint and touch it up.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes, Heh, painting a car has to be one of the hardest DIY things you can possibly do.  Paint restoration maybe, but a full paint job at home is a pretty silly suggestion for 99% of people out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the car is covered in superficial scratches then a good polishing job will work wonders. Take it to a reputable shop and behold how sexy you car has become. You can do it yourself if you have a polishing machine, it will be a huge chore without it.

Note that it won't help against deeper scratches, it is hard to tell from the photo how deep they are in your case. In the case of deep scratches there are kits for reducing their visibility, but are usually oriented towards single deep paint cuts. Many shops do it as well, but don't expect miracles if it is done without part repainting.

Comment: The scratches aren't deep they look like scratches on mobile phone screen.

Comment: In the case of light scratches a proper polishing job should restore the finish.

Comment: Polish did not remove the scratches completely, I can sill see the scratches under light

Comment: Either the scratches are too deep or the polishing job was poorly/improperly executed. Either way, more polishing should yield increasingly better results.